# How to fix this issue that some of the text of the label has been hidden by textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, label

[image]

The text of the label is written programmatically:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    label.Text = data from database;
}
```

Comment: Move the TextBox a bit to the right?

Comment: @MatthewDean, the label is db base so it has different lenghts :)

Comment: Something like: textBox.Location = label.Location + new Size(marginX, textBox.Location.Y);

Comment: my textbox move to bottom, i want label to move not the textbox :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the label's MaximumSize.Width property so it cannot overlap the TextBox.  If you don't have enough space vertically then also set the MaximumSize.Height property.  You then should also consider setting AutoEllipsis to True so that it is obvious to the user that the text got truncated, a tooltip shows the full text.

An easy way to determine the proper values for MaximumSize is to temporarily turn AutoSize off.  Adjust the label size to the maximum size that doesn't overlap anything.  Copy/paste the Size into AutoSize.  Or leave it off.

Comment: is there other to just move automatically the label to left side?

Answer (score 1):

You could set the `Dock` property each of the controls. Depending on your layout you can set each of them to `DockStyle.Left` and set the `AutoSize` property of the label to true. If you can't dock them as is, you can put them inside of a panel and dock inside of the panel. When inside of the panel you can also take advantage of the Fill style of docking (which would also work outside of the panel, but depending on the rest of the controls in your layout it could screw them up. Inside of a panel you can set the label to `DockStyle.Left` and the TextBox to `DockStyle.Fill` (to take up the rest of the space)